# How to move the files of a replicated database (SQL Server 2008 R2) to a different drive

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, replication, transactional-replication

I would appreciate if someone could help me with the following problem:

We use two SQL Server 2008 R2 databases under transactional replication: transactional publication with updatable subscriptions. because we run out of disk space we need to move the database files into a new drive. But I don't want to break the replication.

What I'm looking for are the required steps that will help me to move the files to the new drive.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. alter database [publisher] modify file (name = 'logical_name', filename = 'new_path')
2. alter database [publisher] set offline
3. physically move the files from the old location to the new
4. alter database [publisher] set online

Keep in mind that the logreader agent will hold a connection open to the publisher.  You can stop the agent w/o breaking anything.  Just remember to start it back up again. :)

Comment: Everything worked as you describe above! Thanks Ben!

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure there are no other active SQL sessions to the publisher database or setting it to offline will fail.

-GFT